# Hiding string values in Parse data browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is it possible to hide the content of a specified column of a Parse class in the data browser? I just wanna make some column's values private. Is it possible or do I have to implement my own logic and upload the encrypted objects?

Comment: Even though the UI looks a little like a shared spreadsheet, I don't think it's intended to be used that way.  You'll need to encrypt or not include a column in order to hide it from someone who has data browser access to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only the user password is the hidden field in the data browser, so all else will display whatever String content you put in.

See https://parse.com/questions/hidden-values-in-the-data-browser.